# How to fix 'kernel panic'?

Tags: boot, partitioning, kernel

On Ubuntu 14.04 I was updating some packages, did a reboot and found a kernel panic:

```
run-init: /sbin/init: No such file or directory
Target filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init
run-init: /sbin/init: No such file or directory
run-init: /etc/init: Permission denied     
run-init: /sbin/init: No such file or directory
/bin/sh: 0: Can't open splash
... Kernel Panic...
etc...
```

I booted the laptop with gparted-live USB stick and checked the partitions, which seem to be ok. So it does not seem to be a corrupted partition.

Any quick fixes? Or better wait one day to install Ubuntu 18.04 from scratch...?

Comment: Personally, I'd wait the one day for the release of 18.04 and do a vanilla install rather than attempt to fix an older version. Make sure you maintain information on any packages you currently use which you would like to feature in the new version.

Comment: Did you find a solution?